# CakePHP: use validation functions directly

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I have an AJAX controller that handles all of the AJAX related calls on my CakePHP website. One of those AJAX calls is sending an e-mail, and that function doesn't transact any data to or from the database. I would still like to be able to validate things like an e-mail address while I am doing this AJAX e-mail, but I am not sure how to do that using CakePHP. Can I access the validation functions directly or is there another/better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most definitely can. Use the [`Validation`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/validation) class.

Example:

```
<?php

// Get an instance of the Validation class.
$validation =& Validation::getInstance();

// Validate the e-mail address.
if (!$validation->email('stack@example.com')) {
  // Do something useful since validation failed.
}
```

If the `Validation` class isn't found, you can try importing it using `App::import('Core', 'Validation');`.

Have a look at [How do you perform Form validation without a model in Cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154395/how-do-you-perform-form-validation-without-model-in-cakephp) for a similar question.

Comment: If you are using Cakephp  2.0, `App::import('Core', 'Validation');` will not work. Instead, using `App::uses('Validation', 'Utility');` will do.